# "String in" only works if the reference string is the first string in the sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I know the title is a bit confusing, but what it means is this:

`abdc123` is my reference string and I want to know if this string appears on all other strings. Here's the code:

```
if ref_string in target_string:
print("True")
```

if `target_string` says something like `"abcd123 asdf789 bnc1222"`, it will return as `True`.

However if `target_string` says something like `"asdf789 bnc1222 abcd123"`, it will now say `False` even if `abcd123` is clearly there. It only works if `abcd123` is the first string? How can I fix this? Thanks a lot!

PS: `target_string` is a string, not a list. It's like a sentence.

Comment: `abdc123 != abcd123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string `target_string` which casts it to a list and then compare `ref_string` with that list as follows:

```
ref_string='abdc123'
target_string="abdc123 asdf789 bnc1222"
a=target_string.split()
if ref_string in a:
    print("True")
else:
    print('False')
```

Edit: As mentioned in the comment `in` works on the string as well, and yes that is another method and it works fine too.

```
ref_string='abdc123'
target_string="asdf789 dfbfb abdc123"
if ref_string in target_string:
    print("True")
else:
    print('False')
```

Comment: ```in``` operator would work on the string

Answer (score 1):

If I take the reference and target strings which you specified, I get a `True` as expected:

```
ref_string = "abcd123"
target_string = "asdf789 bnc1222 abcd123"
print(ref_string in target_string)
```

This outputs `True`.

Note that in the opening line to your question, you've referenced a subtly different string (`abdc123`), so do make sure to check that your reference string really *is* in the target.